# animation to transition between views with rotation on z-axis with depth perception

Tags: android, layout, animation

I'm trying to create an animation to transition between two views, both of which are ExpandableListViews.  The look I want is described in the image below.

I tried using a shrink_to_middle and grow_from_middle as the out/in animations of my ViewAnimator - and it's close, but not quite right - with my current shrink/grow, as the animation is taking place, both the right and left edges of the views are the same height, which does not provide any depth to the animation.

I'm not sure how best to explain what I want, which is why I drew the image, but here goes anyways...  I want to have a 3-d look to the animation where the view is rotated on the z-axis.  Assuming we use a simple shrink_to_middle and grow_from_middle animation as the starting point (which does not provide a 3-d look.)  To provide the 3-d look, the out animation would have the right edge get progressively smaller as the view shrinks to the middle; the in animation would have the left edge get progressively larger as the view grows from the middle.

Images 1 through 4 would be the out animation (for view #1) and images 5-8 would be the in animation (for view #2)

[image: animation to transition between views]

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**:
FYI, Here are my current shrink to middle and grow from middle animation xml files

shrink_to_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" android:fillAfter="false" android:duration="500" />
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="50%"
        android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

grow_from_middle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" android:fillAfter="false" android:startOffset="200"
        android:duration="500" />
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:startOffset="200" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rotate3dAnimation is the answer.  It is in the samples SDK folder.  I'm using out animation of 0 to -90 and in animation of 90 to 0 and it works great.

Comment: I not found this sample, he is in the sample of which api?

Comment: If you have API19 you can find Rotate3dAnimation.java here: android-sdk\samples\android-19\legacy\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\animation.

Comment: If you are running the API demos app: Views > Animation > 3D Transition

Comment: i want animation like one machine handle i drag it and after it will rotate down and back to up

Comment: See ftp://ftp.gunadarma.ac.id/android/sdk/sdk_310712/docs/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html for a source code. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014423/how-to-make-rotate3danimation-more-smoother for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do almost same thing. Only difference is that I had to rotate a `MapView`. May be it is too late to answer this question, but I think this may be useful for others. Use [Rotate3dAnimation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html) as follows.

```
public class EventsActivity extends MapActivity implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    private EventsItemModel     eventsItemModel;
    private Integer             eventItemId;
    private Integer             eventCategoryId;
    private static MapOverlay   mapOverlay;
    Drawable                    marker;
    Context                     context;
    private static String       MY_LOCATION = "My Location";
    private ViewGroup           mContainer;
    private ImageView           mImageView;
    private MapView             mMapView;
    private static boolean      isFlipped   = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event_item_detail);
        mContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.event_container);
        // Since we are caching large views, we want to keep their cache
        // between each animation
        mContainer.setPersistentDrawingCache(ViewGroup.PERSISTENT_ANIMATION_CACHE);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mapPreview);

        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isFlipped = true;
                applyRotation(1, 0, 90);
            }
        });

        try {
            eventCategoryId = getIntent().getIntExtra(AppConstants.EVENT_CATEGORY, 0);
            eventItemId = getIntent().getIntExtra(AppConstants.EVENT_ID, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        WeakReference<EventsActivity> weakContext = new WeakReference<EventsActivity>(this);
        EventsAsyncTask task = new EventsAsyncTask(weakContext);
        task.execute(eventItemId, eventCategoryId);
    }

    public void onTaskComplete(EventsItemModel eiModel) {
        this.eventsItemModel = eiModel;
        TextView calTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        TextView eventTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_event_title);
        TextView calDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_date);
        TextView calTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_time);
        TextView calAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_address);
        TextView calDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cal_description);

        try {
            calTitle.setText(eventsItemModel.getEventsCategory().getTitle());
            calTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            eventTitle.setText(eventsItemModel.getEventTitle());
            calDate.setText(eventsItemModel.getFormattedDateRange());
            // TODO:Format start and end time
            calTime.setText("Time: " + eventsItemModel.getFormattedStartTime() + " - " + eventsItemModel.getFormattedEndTime());
            calAddress.setText(eventsItemModel.getAddress());
            calDescription.setText(eventsItemModel.getDescription());
            System.out.println("<<<<<<<<< EventsActivity >>>>>>>>> isRead? " + eventsItemModel.getReadUnread());
            eventsItemModel.setReadUnread(true);
            System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<< EventsActivity >>>>>>>>>> isRead? " + eventsItemModel.getReadUnread());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        setMapParameters();
        createItemizedOverlay();
        setLocationMarker(createMarker(R.drawable.location_marker));
        showLocationPointOnMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    public void createItemizedOverlay() {
        mapOverlay = new MapOverlay(this);
    }

    public void setLocationMarker(Drawable marker) {
        mapOverlay.setLocationMarker(marker);
    }

    public void showLocationPointOnMap() {

        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
        if (eventsItemModel != null && eventsItemModel.getLatitude() != null && eventsItemModel.getLatitude().length() > 0 && eventsItemModel.getLongitude() != null
                && eventsItemModel.getLongitude().length() > 0) {
            try {
                geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(eventsItemModel.getLatitude()) * 1E6), (int) (Double.parseDouble(eventsItemModel.getLongitude()) * 1E6));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, MY_LOCATION, null);
            mapOverlay.addItem(item);
            mMapView.getOverlays().add(mapOverlay);

            // move to location
            mMapView.getController().animateTo(geoPoint);
            // redraw map
            mMapView.postInvalidate();
        }

    }

    public void setStreetView(boolean isStreetView) {
        mMapView.setStreetView(isStreetView);
    }

    public void setSatelliteView(boolean isSatelliteView) {
        mMapView.setSatellite(isSatelliteView);
    }

    public void setZoom(int zoomLevel) {
        mMapView.getController().setZoom(zoomLevel);
    }

    private void setMapParameters() {
        // setStreetView(true);
        // setSatelliteView(false);
        setZoom(17);
    }

    private Drawable createMarker(int iconID) {
        // Initialize icon
        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(iconID);
        icon.setBounds(0, 0, icon.getIntrinsicWidth(), icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return icon;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Setup a new 3D rotation on the container view.
     * 
     * @param position
     *            the item that was clicked to show a picture, or -1 to show the list
     * @param start
     *            the start angle at which the rotation must begin
     * @param end
     *            the end angle of the rotation
     */
    private void applyRotation(int position, float start, float end) {
        // Find the center of the container
        final float centerX = mContainer.getWidth() / 2.0f;
        final float centerY = mContainer.getHeight() / 2.0f;

        // Create a new 3D rotation with the supplied parameter
        // The animation listener is used to trigger the next animation
        final Rotate3dAnimation rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(start, end, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, true);
        rotation.setDuration(500);
        rotation.setFillAfter(true);
        rotation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        rotation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayNextView(position));

        mContainer.startAnimation(rotation);
    }

    /**
     * This class listens for the end of the first half of the animation. It then posts a new action that effectively swaps the views when the container is rotated 90 degrees and thus invisible.
     */
    private final class DisplayNextView implements Animation.AnimationListener {
        private final int   mPosition;

        private DisplayNextView(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            mContainer.post(new SwapViews(mPosition));
        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // Do nothing!!
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class is responsible for swapping the views and start the second half of the animation.
     */
    private final class SwapViews implements Runnable {
        private final int   mPosition;

        public SwapViews(int position) {
            mPosition = position;
        }

        public void run() {
            final float centerX = mContainer.getWidth() / 2.0f;
            final float centerY = mContainer.getHeight() / 2.0f;
            Rotate3dAnimation rotation;

            if (mPosition > -1) {
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mMapView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMapView.requestFocus();

                rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(-90, 180, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, false);
                rotation.reset();
            }
            else {
                mMapView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageView.requestFocus();

                rotation = new Rotate3dAnimation(90, 0, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, false);
            }

            rotation.setDuration(100);
            rotation.setFillAfter(true);
            rotation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

            mContainer.startAnimation(rotation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (isFlipped) {
            applyRotation(-1, 0, -90);
            isFlipped = false;
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

My xml layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/event_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#426773" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/news_header"
        layout="@layout/news_header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cal_event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_header"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/date_time_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/cal_event_title">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cal_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cal_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/cal_date"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mapPreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cal_event_title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"       
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_event_map"
        android:onClick="showMap"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cal_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/date_time_container"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cal_address"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cal_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:apiKey="your_google_api_key"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sample of 3D rotation animation, you can see in [FlipAnimationExample](http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/#svn/trunk/FlipAnimatorExample). But you shouldn't use this anim if your views are heavy, because it makes rotation not smooth, as I see.

For more animations, you can easily find in my "[Android UI Patterns](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns)" app, in Home > Animation & Effect.