# Animate adding item and item movement in listview like Google Plus app

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to reproduce the effect on an listview item when it appears when the user scroll in the listview.

I would like to reproduce the same effect as the Google Plus application.

How can i do this ?

UPDATE :

Here is an extract of my code in my getView() :

```
    final float centerX = rowView.getWidth() / 2.0f;
    final float centerY = rowView.getHeight() / 2.0f;

    rowView.startAnimation(new Rotate3dAnimation(0.0f, -90.0f, centerX, centerY, 310.0f, true));
```

UPDATE 2 :

```
02-12 16:01:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(21625): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 16:01:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(21625):    at com.rss.home.ArticleListAdapterHome.getView(ArticleListAdapterHome.java:129)
02-12 16:01:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(21625):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
02-12 16:01:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(21625):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
02-12 16:01:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(21625):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
02-12 16:01:17.198: E/AndroidRuntime(21625):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
```

Comment: A description of the effect would help. I don't know the g+ app.

Comment: @MalaKa : I have done a record of the effect : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5uiJlSSk9dZcEIxMWw0X0gtVWs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the video.
This looks like a 3D-Rotation to me. The animation is probably started in the `getView` method of the adapter. This means there are three steps to do:

1. Check for custom `ListAdapter`, e.g. [here](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/19/android-listview-with-viewholder-tutorial/). You will also find a lot of questions/answers on so
2. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937149/1798304) to see how to start an animation in `getView`
3. Check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7709176/1798304). It describes where to find an example for 3D-Animation

I haven't checked for 3D-Animation myself, but the `ListAdapter` and the `Animation` on it should not be a big problem.

---

**Edit**:
You don't have to load the animation from xml. You may do it like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // normal handling
    // ...
    // now apply animation
    view.startAnimation(new Rotate3dAnimation(/*params*/));
}
```

---

**Edit2**:
I have now tested it myself, here are things I changed to make it working:

1. I forgot to set the duration of an animation, I did set this
2. The height and width of the view are not set in `getView`, so removed the parameters `centerX` and `centerY` and added `View view` and gave it the `rowView`
3. The animation is using `camera.rotateY`, but this needs to be changed to `camera.rotateX`

This is my updated Rotate3dAnimation:

```
package de.malaka.player.animation;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

/**
 * An animation that rotates the view on the Y axis between two specified angles.
 * This animation also adds a translation on the Z axis (depth) to improve the effect.
 */
public class Rotate3dAnimation extends Animation {
private final float mFromDegrees;
private final float mToDegrees;
private final float mDepthZ;
private final View mView;
private final boolean mReverse;
private Camera mCamera;

/**
 * Creates a new 3D rotation on the Y axis. The rotation is defined by its
 * start angle and its end angle. Both angles are in degrees. The rotation
 * is performed around a center point on the 2D space, definied by a pair
 * of X and Y coordinates, called centerX and centerY. When the animation
 * starts, a translation on the Z axis (depth) is performed. The length
 * of the translation can be specified, as well as whether the translation
 * should be reversed in time.
 *
 * @param fromDegrees the start angle of the 3D rotation
 * @param toDegrees the end angle of the 3D rotation
 * @param centerX the X center of the 3D rotation
 * @param centerY the Y center of the 3D rotation
 * @param reverse true if the translation should be reversed, false otherwise
 */
public Rotate3dAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float depthZ, boolean reverse, View view) {
    mFromDegrees = fromDegrees;
    mToDegrees = toDegrees;
    mDepthZ = depthZ;
    mReverse = reverse;
    mView = view;
}

@Override
public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
    super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    mCamera = new Camera();
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    final float fromDegrees = mFromDegrees;
    float degrees = fromDegrees + ((mToDegrees - fromDegrees) * interpolatedTime);

    final float centerX = mView.getWidth()/2;
    final float centerY = mView.getHeight()/2;
    final Camera camera = mCamera;

    final Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();

    camera.save();
    if (mReverse) {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * interpolatedTime);
    } else {
        camera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mDepthZ * (1.0f - interpolatedTime));
    }
    camera.rotateX(degrees);
    camera.getMatrix(matrix);
    camera.restore();

    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
}
}
```

And this is how I use it in the adapter:

```
Animation anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(90.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, false, convertView);
anim.setDuration(1000l);
convertView.startAnimation(anim);
```

The duration is pretty long right now, but this way you can adjust the values.

Comment: Thanks for your analyze and for links. I have found the Rotate3dAnimation.java, i also added the code in my getView() method, but how can i use the java file because loadAnimation method required xml file for the animation? (   'Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_top_to_bottom);
         v.startAnimation(animation);)'

Comment: Thanks. Have you an idea of which params can i specify to reproduce the animation that i want?

Comment: I guess the center of the `View` is your `centerX` and `centerY`, and `toDegrees` will be 0, `fromDegrees` maybe 45 (or -45, you need to tes t that) and you also have to play around with the `depthZ`, I have no idea how exactly the effect of `depthZ` will look like..

Comment: @wawanopoulos I got it working now, please check the second update of my answer.

Comment: I got an exception (nullPointerException). Please consult my update2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47331/discussion-between-malaka-and-wawanopoulos)