# Change ImageView Width from top and bottom seperate

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am trying to change the width of `ImageView` from top and bottom separately. I want the width from top left-right to 100dp and from bottom left-right to 50dp. See the attached image for an idea:

[image: ]]

I tried to do find a solution online but I did not find anything yet. I tried with the Android Scale library but I could not achieve the required result with it.

```
ScaleAnimation fade_in =  new ScaleAnimation(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        fade_in.setDuration(1000);     // animation duration in milliseconds
        fade_in.setFillAfter(true);    // If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished.
        IV.startAnimation(fade_in);
```

Please guide me which library is capable of doing it or how it can be achieved?

Comment: You can Transform/rotate the Imageview on z-axis. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705549/animation-to-transition-between-views-with-rotation-on-z-axis-with-depth-percept)

Comment: This link maybe help you https://devdeeds.com/create-triangle-shape-using-xml-android/

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom shape `ImageView` using [this library](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview)

Comment: I don't want to create shape because i am changing values at run time

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an XML file for your background image view and shape the Trapezius.
you have not to use any library.

attention: I used color for solid and etc because of you (copy and paste it to your The XML file and watch it ).

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <padding android:top="35dp"/>
        <size android:width="200dp" android:height="40dp" />
        <solid android:color="#13a89e" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="line">
        <size android:width="100dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#123456" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:right="-200dp"
    android:left="200dp"
    android:top="-200dp"
    android:bottom="-200dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <padding android:top="-35dp"/>
           <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item
    android:right="200dp"
    android:left="-200dp"
    android:top="-200dp"
    android:bottom="-200dp">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:top="-35dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create your custom `Imageview`
and with custom `Imageview` you can scale it with animation and animate `path` using `ValueAnimator` as per your requirment.

```
public class CustomImage extends AppCompatImageView {
    private Path path;

    public CustomImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    private void init(){
        path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float h = getMeasuredHeight();
        float w = getMeasuredWidth();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(w, 0);
        path.lineTo(w * 0.8f, h);
        path.lineTo(w * 0.2f, h);
        path.lineTo(0, 0);
        path.close();
        canvas.clipPath(path);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }


}
```

[image]